# React native with mongodb realm. Attempting google signin results in error code 10

Tags: react-native, realm, mongodb-realm

Below code is provided at realm docs.

```
GoogleSignin.configure({
  webClientId: clientId,
  offlineAccess: true,
});
async function getGoogleAuthCode() {
  try {
    await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();    
    const {serverAuthCode} = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
    return serverAuthCode;
  } 
catch (error) {}
```

Above code always returns 10 - DEVELOPER_ERROR,

Cross checked the client id. Since mongodb realm suggests to use web application type google oAuth. App's SHA is not registered at google end.

Answer (score 0):

Google sign in is broken in the current beta.

References:

- [Open GitHub Issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/3116) involving 3 different Realm SDKs
- [MongoDB Developer Forum post confirming](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/problems-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2/7639/3) this is a problem on their side.